# Creating text file from jinja template with inputs from csv file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to create a text file which goes through the  CSV file and populates variables into specific fields. 
playbook.yml:

```
   - hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "Reading user information"
      read_csv:
        path: /home/test/vlans.csv
        delimiter: ','
      register: vlans
    - debug: var=vlans
    - name: Creating VLANs configuration
      template:
        src: vlan.conf.j2
        dest: /tmp/vlan.conf
```

Jinja2 Template vlan.conf.j2:

```
{% for item in vlans %}
!
vlan {{ item.VLAN }}
    name {{ item.Description }}
            vn-segment {{ item.VNI }}



interface nve1
   member vni {{ item.VNI }}


 {% endfor %}
```

and this is a test vlans.csv file:

```
Tenant,VRF ,VLAN,VNI,Subnet,Description,Good to go
Test,,5,20005,,LAB-Checkpoint-FW-Mgmt,Yes
Test,,208,20208,,LAB-DMZ,Yes Test,,209,20209,,LAB-CSR-MGMT,Yes
Test,10000,210,20210,192.168.12.1/28,LAB-VRF-to-FW,Yes
Prod,,761,20761,,PROD-CORE,Yes
Prod,105,840,20840,172.18.33.1/24,Backups,Yes
Prod,,841,20841,,Transport,Yes
```

I want to end up with file like in jinja2 template and not repeating line "interface nve 1"

Comment: Could you please include an example of the desired output.  It's not clear what the issue is with the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, `interface nve1` is inside a loop. It will repeat multiple times in the resulting vlan.conf file.

Use multiple loops in the jinja template to decide what is repeated and what isn't:

```
{% for item in vlans.list %}
vlan {{ item.VLAN }}
    name {{ item.Description }}
    vn-segment {{ item.VNI }}

{% endfor %}

interface nve1
{% for item in vlans.list %}
   member vni {{ item.VNI }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that I've referred to `vlans.list` in the start of the loops instead of `vlans`. This is correct as per [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/read_csv_module.html), but different to the example in the question so it may need adjusting.